# HTTP Requests with cookies on chrome extension

Tags: angularjs, ajax, http, cookies, postman

I have been several days trying to understand how a chrome extension is working when a HTTP request is made.

I am using YARC (Yet Another Rest Client) Chrome extension. But I guess it works same for all. Even Postman.

First thing I see is when I make the request if I am using an http traffic viewer like fiddler, I can see the host is the same I am making the request (Like www.google.com) and if I make an Ajax request or a php request the host is the same i have the script (like localhost).

The other thing is that I am making a POST request to a site to make a login that set a cookie. If I make it with the chrome extension, the cookie is set on my browser and then I could navigate normally on that page and the cookie is set and I am logged in. If I make this post with Ajax or PHP i´ts impossible to set this cookie because my host is in a different domain (localhost).

I can see I could make a submit post for this, but then I got redirected after the submit and it´s impossible to avoid that. I would like to manage the response like the extension as it was an Ajax call.

The main thing I see here is that thy host is always on same domain and this could avoid all this problems. But HOW? Looking for YARC code I can see they make this request as a regular http angularjs, it means Ajax I am almost sure. Anywhay not even trying with angularjs http I can get this to work.

What I actually would need to do is how this Chrome extension could make this and how to set this cookie when I make this POST, I mean, the Host set the cookie on their own domain, cause I can get the cookie but not to set it and I know it is impossible from a different domain.

Thanks in advance for all your help.